# Explicit HSTS Preload Specification

Tags: ssl, https, preload, hsts

Senario 1:
If a domain (example.com) is registered in the Preload list managed at https://hstspreload.org/, do subdomains such as sub.example.com need to explicitly set the preload option in their response headers if example.com already has preload specified? How would someone accessing sub.example.com know that example.com has preload specified? Is there some type of invisible request that is made to example.com to check if the domain at example.com requires preloading? If not, would the browser just rely on the fact that the domain is registered at hstspreload.org and know to do HTTPS from the start?

Scenario 2:
If example.com doesn't respond to requests (i.e. there is only responses to sub.example.com),  and the subdomains don't have preload specified, there is no way to know that the example.com domain requires the preload to be set. Would preloading work in this scenario where the example.com domain doesn't respond to requests (hence, example.com doesn't indicate that preloading is required), or doesn't it matter since example.com is registered with hstspreload.org? I do know that the Submission Requirements indicates that there is a requirement to "serve an HSTS header on the base domain for the HTTPS requests", so I presume we would need to have a DNS entry for example.com which returns a page with the header with the required fields of preload and includesubdomains.

All of the above questions are assuming that includesubdomains is specified.

Comment: The submission requirements of the page you link to should pretty much answer your first paragraph (you don't preload a name, but everything at or below it, which is why some registries did add their TLDs in the preload list). The preloading list is hardcoded in the browsers, which should answer almost all of your other questions (that are offtopic here as not related to programming): browsers know, without doing any external queries, which websites should be HSTS or not, because they are preloaded.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the purpose of specifying the preload in the header if the preload list is checked? I may be overthinking all of this but there are some nuances I am trying to figure out.

Comment: "So what is the purpose of specifying the preload in the header if the preload list is checked? " Mostly as safeguard, not technically required (using a preloaded list is exactly the answer against having the HSTS header, because that creates a loop in dependency), but also allowing a way to remove an entry from preloading, as such: "Note that removing the preload directive from your header will make your site immediately eligible for the removal form, and that sites may be removed automatically in the future for failing to keep up the requirements. "

Comment: Note that HSTS and the preloading list do work but are kind of past ideas now. Nowadays (or very soon), in theory, the simple use of DNS records of `HTTPS/SVCB` and `TLSA` (DANE) should cater for the same needs in a far better fashion (decentralized control where the preloaded list is centralized obviously, and dynamic changes under control of the rightful owner of the name). But browsers do not support `TLSA`... Yet they do already implement `HTTPS` DNS records consumption for multiple of them.